# Replacing a character in string

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void replace (char a[]){
    char *y;
    *y = 'm';
    char *p = a;
    p = strchr(p, 'g');
    while (p){
        *p = *y;
        p++;
        p = strchr(p, 'g');
    }
}

int main (){
    char x[10];
    gets(x);
    replace(x);
    puts(x);
    return 0;
}
```

What's wrong with this replace function?
It doesn't output a string instead it says segmentation fault.

Comment: `char *y;` --> `char y = 'm';`.. `*p = y;`

Comment: Working fine  on online compiler :  http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/uuMv89

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to write to a [wild pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) here:

```
char *y;
*y = 'm';
```

`y` doesn't point anywhere in particular, so you get Undefined Behaviour (a seg fault in your particular case).

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning value using an uninitialized pointer, y.
Why do you use pointer y anyway, instead of

```
*p = *y;
```

you can just say

```
*p = 'm';
```

Answer (score 1):

y is not allocated. It is just a pointer and a pointer must point to a space in the memory. But you didn't allocate any space in the memory. So when you defferentiate it, is going to deferentiate the garbage address that a non itialized pointer has. Crash...
So rather than

```
char *y; 
*y='p';
```

just write:

```
char y='p'; ///no pointer
```

Then a first improvment at the function. The function is too specific, just for a character, I would write like:

```
void replace (char a[],char from, char to)
{
   char *p = a;
   while(*p)
   {
       if(*p==from) *p=to;
          p++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you compile your program with warnings enabled you should get a warning like this (with the GCC compiler):

```
warning: ‘y’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     *y = 'm';
        ^
```

Before you dereference the pointer *y* you need to know that it points to a valid object, but in your case *y* has not been assigned a value so it can point anywhere. Also you don't need any extra pointer; here is a more concise (and more general) version of the function:

```
static void replace(char old, char new, char s[])
{
    s = strchr(s, old);
    while (s != NULL) {
        *s = new;
        s = strchr(s, old);
    }
}
```

Or without using *strchr*:

```
static void replace(char old, char new, char s[])
{
    int i = 0;

    while (s[i] != '\0') {
        if (s[i] == old) {
            s[i] = new;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```